# Cannot get background image to take on full height

Tags: css, background-image

I have a background image pulling in but it is taking the height of the text not the image, I will eventually do a text-indent: -99999px but I have tried every CSS property to get the whole image to appear. Can anyone help with this, my website is: http://yesiamshow.biz/ it is the buttons under the slideshow, you can see I have the image for previous pulling but it does not show the whole height. All my CSS properties have a height of 60px and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is actually the right height, but your `.window` class is cutting off it off. Looks like you can change it to 410px and it will fix:

```
.window {
   height:410px;
}
```

You should also give the button a `display:block` or inline-block since you're giving it a width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at your CSS and it seems that you are wrapping your link with a span element. You can still do that, however you need to make sure that you are applying all of your styling to the links.

Example. If your HTML was something like.

```
<a span="prev_btn"><a href="#prev">Previous</a></span>
```

You would have to style like so.

```
span.prev_btn a { }
```

And it should look something similar to the following.

```
span.prev_btn a {
 background: [your url];
 display: block;
 height: [height];
 width: [width];
 text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Hope that helped.